# Как сделать пост запрос по клику из расширения chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Мой код открывает новую вкладку с редиректом на указанную страницу,а как сделать POST запрос ?

```
document.getElementById('consoleLogJsonButton')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'http://www.google.com/'
    });
  })
```

Comment: Используйте либу axios или средствами браузера 
XMLHttpRequest, fetch. Вероятно вам еще придется поправить manifest.json, что-бы хром позволил делать запросы из расширения.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то понадобиться,то вот рабочий вариант.

```
document.getElementById('consoleLogJsonButton').addEventListener('click',startSendRequest);

function startSendRequest() {
const json = "json";
const xmlHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new window.XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/ud/theBasik.php", true);
xmlHttpRequest.send("userid=" + json);
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert('Received!');
    }
  }
}
```